# Is it possible to apply imported styles to specific component without parent?

Tags: html, css, less

I use LESS preprocessor.
And here is a deal - I have such HTML code:

```
//index.html

<component class="component _special">
    <div class="child">...</div>
</component>
<component class="component _usual"></component>
```

Another team has some styles (LESS):

```
//styles.less

.component {
   ...
   .child {
      ...
   }
}
```

I need to import their styles, but these styles should be applied only for component with class **_special**. And **I can't wrap** needed components like that:

```
<div class="_special>
    <component ...></component>
</div>
```

Is it possible to apply imported styles somehow, so they would work only for marked "_special" components?

Comment: The variant with ._special { @import "../styles.less" } obviously doesn't work, because it turns to an extra level nesting -> ._special { .component {...} }. But I need ._special.component {...}

Comment: not sure about LESS as I have no experience with it but within CSS you could use `component [class*="_special"] > .child` as selector